# Choosing The Right Git Workflow

Tags: git, jenkins

We are using Git and Jenkins in our team. We don't have any specific workflow, basically it works like :

- clone the project
- create your feature/bugfix branch
- push your codes to the branch you have worked on
- create a pull request from your branch to master then merge it.

The last week we have a situation might be a problem. I had some tasks to go to the sooner release, but my coworker had tasks for the next one. Which means my code on X20 version in `jenkins` and his one is on X21 version. When testing was going on X20 version (this version will be on the sooner release), an error occurred. Then the questions started to come up.

> What if I need to fix my code without taking my coworker changes? 
>   Which workflow would solve my problem? Or don't I need it?  What would
>   you recommend in this case?

Btw : Jenkins provides to deploy `master` and `release` branches. As our release interval is one month (which means many changes would be possible and the tasks place would be change with regards to the releases) we don't want to go for the release branching model.

Any recommendation will be welcomed.

Comment: You're talking about "hotfixes", or quick patches that fall outside the usual build cycle. You'll need to pull these in to your master and wrangle any merge conflicts at that level. Usually someone's the "merge master" who's responsible for this at the top-level, so it ends up being their job to ensure all the pull requests fit together properly.

Comment: Do you run CI builds on jenkins on master and release branch? Continuous integration is a the way to seperate testing per commit.

Comment: @tadman actually there was no conflict because we did not work on the same features. We just wanted to deploy X22 version which includes my codes and my hotfixes but not the codes which is my coworker code in already X21 version.

Comment: This is more a philosophical question than one with a specific answer. I've seen some extremely convoluted "solutions" to this, as well as some stupid-simple ones that just work.

Comment: @rakhee we don’t use release branches. We just use master branch for CI builds on Jenkins

Comment: Have you seen http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/